# Ansible - Filter a dict with a list of keys

Tags: loops, ansible

I have a `list` which is actually a list of keys of a `dict`. And I want to get a concatenated string with the `dict` filtered on this `list` of keys and use it in a module option.

My use case here is users that have a list of public keys's name to generate an authorized_keys file.

```
 1 ---
 2 - hosts: localhost
 3   become: false
 4   vars:
 5     pub_keys:
 6       key01: ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQ[…]5/ someuser@somehost
 7       key02: ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQ[…]ea otheruser@somewher
 8       key03: ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQ[…]dN anyser@anyhost
 9     users:
10       root:
11         home: /root
12         shell: /bin/bash
13         authorized_keys:
14           - key01
15       mgmtusr:
16         home: /home/mgmtusr
17         shell: /bin/bash
18         authorized_keys:
19           - key01
20           - key02
21           - key03
22
23   tasks:
24     - name: Debug Authorized Keys
25       debug:
26         msg: "USER:{{ item.key }} AUTHKEYSLIST:{{ pub_keys|selectattr(item.authorized_keys) }}"
27       with_dict: "{{ users }}"
28
29     - name: Manage users Authorized Keys
30       authorized_key:
31         user: "{{ item.key }}"
32         key: "{{ pub_keys|selectattr(item.authorized_keys) }}"
33         exclusive: yes
34       with_dict: "{{ users }}"
35
```

As you can see here, I give it a try with `dict|selectattr(list)` but it fails.

Getting `<generator object select_or_reject at 0x…>` in the debug module and of course an `invalid key specified` in the authorized_key module.

```
TASK [Debug Authorized Keys] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': u'mgmtusr', 'value': {u'home': u'/home/mgmtusr', u'shell': u'/bin/bash', u'authorized_keys': [u'key01', u'key02', u'key03']}}) => {
    "item": {
        "key": "mgmtusr",
        "value": {
            "authorized_keys": [
                "key01",
                "key02",
                "key03"
            ],
            "home": "/home/mgmtusr",
            "shell": "/bin/bash"
        }
    },
    "msg": "USER:mgmtusr AUTHKEYSLIST:"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': u'root', 'value': {u'home': u'/root', u'shell': u'/bin/bash', u'authorized_keys': [u'key01']}}) => {
    "item": {
        "key": "root",
        "value": {
            "authorized_keys": [
                "key01"
            ],
            "home": "/root",
            "shell": "/bin/bash"
        }
    },
    "msg": "USER:root AUTHKEYSLIST:"
}

TASK [Manage users Authorized Keys] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
failed: [localhost] (item={'key': u'mgmtusr', 'value': {u'home': u'/home/mgmtusr', u'shell': u'/bin/bash', u'authorized_keys': [u'key01', u'key02', u'key03']}}) => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "item": {"key": "mgmtusr", "value": {"authorized_keys": ["key01", "key02", "key03"], "home": "/home/mgmtusr", "shell": "/bin/bash"}}, "msg": "Failed to lookup user mgmtusr: 'getpwnam(): name not found: mgmtusr'"}
failed: [localhost] (item={'key': u'root', 'value': {u'home': u'/root', u'shell': u'/bin/bash', u'authorized_keys': [u'key01']}}) => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "item": {"key": "root", "value": {"authorized_keys": ["key01"], "home": "/root", "shell": "/bin/bash"}}, "msg": "invalid key specified: "}
```

Like other tries (`with_subelements`, `lookup('template'`, …) `selectattr` does not seems the solution.
Any proposition?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go:

```
- name: Manage users Authorized Keys
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.key }}"
    key: "{{ item.value.authorized_keys | map('extract',pub_keys) | list | join('\n') }}"
    exclusive: yes
  with_dict: "{{ users }}"
```

See [extract](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers) filter usage.

Also when you use `map` you should almost always typecast it to `list` to prevent `generator object` value.

Comment: Thanks for that answer!
I read a bit on `map` when searching but didn't get it yet. So definitively now, I have to learn more about that one.